# Python error: List assignment index out of range

Tags: python, list

I am attempting to initialize a list and keep getting the index out of range:

```
self.nodes = [[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[]]
```

When I run this code:

```
for i in range(self.rows):
            for j in range(self.columns):
                if self.GRID[i][j] == 0:
                    self.walkable.append(Node(j * self.cellSize, i * self.cellSize))
                    self.isWalkable = True
                if self.GRID[i][j] == 1:
                    self.unwalkable.append(Node(j * self.cellSize, i * self.cellSize))
                    self.isWalkable = False
                if self.GRID[i][j] == 2:
                    self.player = Node(j * self.cellSize, i * self.cellSize)
                    self.isWalkable = True
                if self.GRID[i][j] == 3:
                    self.npc = Node(j * self.cellSize, i * self.cellSize)
                    self.isWalkable = True

                self.nodes[i][j] = Node(j, i)
                self.nodes[i][j].setWalkable(self.isWalkable)
```

The error I get is:

```
self.nodes[i][j] = Node(j, i)
IndexError: list assignment index out of range
```

Comment: It's impossible to tell you why unless you show the code that sets self.columns and self.rows, since one of these exceeds the array bounds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is `Node()` ?

```
>>> nodes = [[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[]]
>>> nodes[0][0] = 5
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<interactive input>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: list assignment index out of range
>>> nodes[0].append(5)
>>> nodes
[[5], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []]
```

Comment: Solved my issue; hard to adjust to python when I'm too busy thinking in C ;)

Answer (score 2):

Assignment to a non-existent index in a list fails. In your case, you are attempting to assign to index `j` of an empty list:

```
self.nodes = [[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[]]
# assume i == 0 and j == 0
self.nodes[i] # refers to the first empty list []
self.nodes[i][j] ## does not exist
```

Consider replacing `self.nodes[i][j] = Node(j, i)` with `self.nodes[i].append(Node(j, i))`

Alternatively, ensure that `self.nodes` is initialised with nested lists as described by @yi_H

**EDIT** OK, not *exactly* as yi_H described. If you want to create a 2d array representing your table, you can do so with

```
self.nodes = [ [None for col in range(self.cols) ] for row in range(self.rows)]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
self.nodes = [[[]] * self.columns] * self.rows
```

Comment: This is so wrong. The result has one dimension too much and the innermost lists will be the same (appending to any appends to all). Perhaps you meant to initialize it with empty lists as values - but that wouldn't be too useful either (it's not necessary when one uses `.append` like they should, and `None` does a better job as it's immutable and semantically a better fit).

Comment: *sigh*.. I don't know what I was thinking, *sorry*.

Comment: No need to apologise. It may not be correct but it's a useful answer that highlights a common 'mistake'